# Azure function timer trigger fails when I add my script inside __init_.py

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, azure-functions

I have written a python code which gets a json file from a MongoDB database and performs somewhat of an ETL process. My problem is when I run my script on it's own it works perfectly fine, however, when I place the code inside the main **init**.py file so that it can run using a timer trigger it fails.

Am I doing something wrong in the main **init**.py file or is there something i'm missing out?

This is the error i'm receiving when I debug it locally:

```
Executed 'Functions.TestTimerTrigger' (Failed, Id=XXXX, Duration=30285ms)
[2021-01-18T10:41:11.323Z] System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: Functions.TestTimerTrigger. System.Private.CoreLib: Result: Failure
Exception: ServerSelectionTimeoutError: XXXX:27017: timed out, Timeout: 30s, Topology Description: <TopologyDescription id: 600565a938892b2d0c79ba96, topology_type: Single, servers: [<ServerDescription ('XXXX', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=NetworkTimeout('XXXX:27017: timed out')>]>
```

Running my python script on it's own:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
import pandas as pd
from azure.storage.filedatalake import DataLakeServiceClient
from azure.core._match_conditions import MatchConditions
from azure.storage.filedatalake._models import ContentSettings
from pandas import json_normalize
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

mongo_client = MongoClient("XXXX") 
db = mongo_client.x_db #database name
table = db.levels #collection name

document = table.find()
mongo_docs = list(document)
mongo_docs = json_normalize(mongo_docs) 
mongo_docs.to_csv("test.csv", sep = ",", index=False)  

try:  
    global service_client
        
    service_client = DataLakeServiceClient(account_url="{}://{}.dfs.core.windows.net".format(
        "https", "XXXX"), credential='XXXX')
    

    file_system_client = service_client.get_file_system_client(file_system="root") name

    directory_client = file_system_client.get_directory_client("testfolder") 

    file_client = directory_client.create_file("test.csv") 
    local_file = open(r"XXX\test.csv",'rb')
    file_contents = local_file.read()

    file_client.upload_data(file_contents, overwrite=True) 

except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Placed my script into the main *init*.py file:

```
import datetime
import logging
import json
import requests
import azure.functions as func
from pymongo import MongoClient
import pandas as pd
from azure.storage.filedatalake import DataLakeServiceClient
from azure.core._match_conditions import MatchConditions
from azure.storage.filedatalake._models import ContentSettings
from pandas import json_normalize
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

    
def main(mytimer: func.TimerRequest) -> None:
    mongo_client = MongoClient("XXXX") #MongoDB Connection String
    db = mongo_client.x_db #database name
    table = db.levels #collection name

    document = table.find()
    mongo_docs = list(document)
    mongo_docs = json_normalize(mongo_docs) 
    mongo_docs.to_csv("test.csv", sep = ",", index=False)  

    try:  
        global service_client
            
        service_client = DataLakeServiceClient(account_url="{}://{}.dfs.core.windows.net".format(
            "https", "XXXX"), credential='XXXX')
        

        file_system_client = service_client.get_file_system_client(file_system="root") 

        directory_client = file_system_client.get_directory_client("testfolder") 

        file_client = directory_client.create_file("test.csv") #name of file being created
        local_file = open(r"XXXX\test.csv",'rb') #file which you want to open

        file_contents = local_file.read()

        file_client.upload_data(file_contents, overwrite=True)

    except Exception as e:
        print(e) 

    utc_timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(
        tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc).isoformat()

    if mytimer.past_due:
        logging.info('The timer is past due!')

    logging.info('Python timer trigger function ran at %s', utc_timestamp)
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this error message says it all:

> error=NetworkTimeout('XXXX:27017: timed out')

You're connecting to something you can't connect to from the Function App. It either might be inaccessible because it's on a private network, or the Function App wasn't added to the resource's whitelist or the port isn't correct.

Anyhow: make sure the resource you're connecting to from your code is accessible from the Azure Function App.